# kotlin. MutableMap

Tags: kotlin

Есть коллекция и необходимо  пробежаться по ней следующим образом:

```
val l=mapOf(-1.0 to 1.0, 10.0 to 0.0 , 1.0 to 1.0)
    l.keys.forEach{ println(it-1 )}
```

под `println(it-1 )` подразумеваю предыдущий ключ. Две проблемы:1)Как сделать, чтобы действительно возвращал предыдущий ключ, а не значение ключа-1 2)Если первая  проблема будет решена, то что будет возвращено года it будет обозначать самый первый ключ коллекции?

Comment: Так сделать нельзя, эта фича не во всех языках есть

Answer (score 0):

```
fun main() {
    val map = mapOf(-1.0 to 1.0, 10.0 to 0.0 , 1.0 to 1.0)
    
    var x: Double? = null // тут будет храниться предыдущее значение
    
    for ((key, _) in map) {
        if (x != null) {
            // если предыдущее значение есть, используем его
            println("$x")
        } else {
            // предыдущего значения ещё нету, т.к. это первая
            // итерация цикла
            println("null")
        }
        
        // запомним текущий ключ, для вывода его на следующем
        // шаге цикла
        x = key
    }    
}
```

Вывод:

```
null
-1.0
10.0
```